# Unicode char issues in some representations

Tags: browser, unicode

Can anyone explain why only the first character is fragmented in [this](https://jsfiddle.net/cLezabgq/) example?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html/>
<html>
  <body>
    <span></span>
    <span>&#119136;</span>
    <span>&#x1d160;</span>
  </body>
</html>
```

Tested with Chrome 77 and Firefox 70, on Windows and Linux.

This is what I see:

[image: output]

Comment: You are using two characters (code point) on the first case. Possibly it is a font problem/definition of kerning (distance between characters). -- try to change font, or check if there is a unicode way to define that the two are part on the same note (e.g. with a joiner code point).

Comment: Works fine for me using [Symbola](http://users.teilar.gr/~g1951d/). It's definitely a font problem.

Comment: Well, I found that the font used by my system to display this character is [Denemo](https://github.com/denemo/denemo/tree/master/fonts). But I can't still explain why only the first is fragmented. It works well with Symbola or GNU FreeFont.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you get a bug (possibly from the font).

According [Unicode chapter 21](https://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode12.0.0/ch21.pdf), figure 21-2, we have exactly your case:

U+1d160 = U+1d158 + U+1d165 + U+1d16e

so it should be shown as your third character (the second character depend on the encoding of the page).

The font correctly put the last two code point together, but it create too much distance between the first and the second.  This seems contrary to the Unicode standard, so I can just assume it is a bug.

You may check other fonts (possibly webfont) and force to use webfonts for such characters. With webfont you are sure all users will see the same style. But with a short search, I cannot find good free webfonts with music notes.